# Retrieving data from hash table ordered by insertion time

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, hash, hash-tables

By default, a hash table is unordered.  I have a simple question on the retrieval of elements in a hash table

> Can we retrieve elements from a hash table in the same order as they are put inside?

Comment: Have you seen it stated that you can? Or are you interested in developing a method to do so?

Comment: It's unclear whether you are interested in the insertion points of the _keys_ or the _values_ corresponding to the keys.  This might make a difference if you want to make an auxiliary data structure handling this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've put an element in any kind of container data structure like map or set, ordered or unordered, the data structure no longer remembers the order in which you called `insert()`.  (The "ordered/unordered" distinction is whether the data structure keeps the elements in order by their key with respect to the less-than operator.)

If you want to know the order in which some events happened you will need to keep another container data structure, or some auxiliary information in the objects you are storing.  For example if you want to be able to iterate through in the order in which you inserted: keep both an `unordered_map` *and* a `vector` of references to the objects you inserted.  Every time you do an insertion you also `push_back` a reference to what you just inserted.  (But be careful, if you are doing this in C++, that you aren't also removing objects from the unordered map, because then the references in the vector will become invalid.)

If you want a number associated with each element stored in the map ("this was the 42nd inserted"), then you should augment your `map` datatype with, (a) a global counter and (b) a way to store both an object and a number (e.g., store `struct {T the_object; int insert_order;}` instead of objects of type `T`), and (c) wrap the `insert` operators so that they increment the counter and insert the new number along with the new object.